# In Nested ListView, how to set onItemClick of the inner view to inherit its parent's one?

Tags: android, listview, gridview

this is my first question on stackoverflow.

My problem is, in my Android APP, there is a ListView with some Items, and on click of each item will transit to a new fragment. In the Item itself, there is a inner GridView to display some dynamic data from an array.

My concern is that, if I click the item of that inner GridView, it will not call the ListView's onItemClick method and will do nothing (because I have set it disabled). What I want is to set these inner items not clickable just like TextView in the List Item.

Here is the lines where I set adapter to the inner GridView inside getView method of the parent adapter.

```
MyListAdapter{
......
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ......
    grid.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this.mContext,R.layout.item,list));
    grid.setEnabled(false);
    return convertView;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have try to use android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" on list view.

Answer (score 0):

The click is only on the top most layer. You have to add the listener to each item of the grid view.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup.

View with ListView in it. And each view of the ListView has another Listview:

```
.ListView
...View1
......ListView
.........View1.1

...View2
......ListView
.........View2.1
```

I wanted to clicks on View1.1 & 2.1 to be redirected to their parent ListView onItemClick().

So I tried to add this to the nested ListViews getDataRow() methods:

```
((ListView) parent).performItemClick(finalScrapView, position, 0);
```

It did **not** work.

My solution was to call a method defined in the parent ListView's activity/class.

The nested ListViews getDataRow() method now has:

```
 ((MyActivity)parent).TestMethod();
```

And the MyActivity class method is defined (as an example) as:

```
public void teste()
{
    Toast.makeText(App.getInstance().getApplicationContext(), "TESTE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Not the best implementation, but since the performItemClick was not working and I could not get stuck there forever, I had to do this 'cheat'.

Hope it helps somehow.